# Efficient way to Load the scene and Scene Render optimization

Tags: unity-game-engine

Our unity3d Most of the Scenes are **too heavy**. What is the *right way* and *efficient way* to load the scene.?? Please dont refer me **LoadLevelAsync** I have already see that! What is the best practice to load heavy scene without any problem and un-smoothness.

Comment: Ideally, you don't want to load everything you will ever use in a scene at the very start - try to only load what you need in the scene to get it started. Figure out what items you can instantiate/pool as the scene progresses, rather than loading them all up right off the bat. Alternatively, try to hide the drop in performance by stopping the action, doing something like fading the screen to black and just having a loading icon animating there.

Comment: so, there is no only special tips and tricks? i just need to load it manually?

Answer (score 1):

For which platform you are building?

The heaviest thing to load in Unity are Textures. If you are using too much of them in the scene, make sure that they are compressed and try to reduce their max size in the inspector. If you can't see any improvement, consider creating a loading screen transition after calling Application.LoadLevel("YourBigLevel"). 
You can add an Activity indicator if you are running the app on iOS or Android devices.

Comment: so the trick is only use texture compress in order to enhance efficient loading?

Comment: Yes, Unity  takes more time to load uncompressed textures than compressed ones. Try also to reduce their max size for the target that you are building for (select the texture --> go to the inspector --> max size)